# Variable is not visible: [controller].field_disp

Tags: visualforce, access-modifier

I have a managed package which uses a VF page and controller. This works fine in the developer environment, but starts throwing an error in the installed env.

> Variable is not visible: [namespace.controller].field_disp

The VF page get displayed in the installed env, but when we save the page we get the above error.  Any thoughts what could be the reason

```
public with sharing class ctrl_Candidate_Site{


    public Candidates__c ca_Insert {get; set;} // For inserting Candidates records 
    public blob Attach {get;set;}  // For attaching Resume to the specific record
    public String fileName {get; set;}
    public Attachment a {get; set;}
    public Id jobID {get; set;}// To get the ID from URL
    public Boolean isSaved{get; set;}// To know is saved successfully
    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> candidateFields{get; set;}
    public map<string, Candidates__c> fieldMap {get; set;}
    public map<string, string> fieldMap_api {get; set;}
    public Candidates__c field_disp {get;set;}


    public ctrl_Candidate_Site(){    
        ca_Insert = new Candidates__c(); 
        //ca_Insert = (Candidates__c)stdController.getRecord(); // getting records from VF page 
        jobID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('jobId'); // Getting the jobId from URL   
        candidateFields = new List<Schema.FieldSetMember> ();
        a = new Attachment();  
        system.debug('Fieldset values ' + candidateFields );

        fieldMap = new map<string, Candidates__c>();
        fieldMap_api = new map<string, string>();
        field_disp = new Candidates__c ();  

    }       



    public PageReference SaveResult(){

             system.debug('Candidate entered value from VF page  ' + field_disp); 
             field_disp.Name = field_disp.First_Name__c + ' ' +field_disp.Last_Name__c;         

             //If job Id not equals to null then add the postion to the job.
             if(jobID != null ){
                field_disp.Position__c = jobID;
             }
}
}
```

VF page

```
  <table class="tableStyle">              
             <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f"> 

                    <tr>

                         <!--  <td class="tdStyleFirst">  -->
                         <td class="tdStyleFirst">       
                             <apex:outputText value="{!f.Label}"  ></apex:outputText>                    
                              <!-- <apex:Output value="{!field_disp[f.Label]}" /> --> </td> 
                         <td>

                              <apex:inputField value="{!field_disp[f.fieldPath]}" required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}"/></td>                         
                    </tr>        

              </apex:repeat> 
                      <tr>
                          <td>Attach Resumes</td>
                          <td><apex:inputFile value="{!Attach}" accept="doc, docx, txt, pdf" filesize="1000" filename="{!fileName}"></apex:inputFile> </td>
                      </tr> 
                      <tr>
                          <td></td>                          
                          <td> <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveResult}" value="Submit"/>
                               <apex:commandButton action="{!reset}" value="Reset" /> </td>
                      </tr>

              </table>
```

UPDATE 1:

This seems to work in another dev org where i have installed the managed package. The profiles etc seem to be same. Not sure why it would throw this error on client org

UPDATE 2:

Looks like the issue is only when i try to serve page using a template outside the managed package. If i use the template which is part of the managed package then all works fine.

Comment: Not sure that this correlates with the error message, but as you are accessing the `field_disp` fields by name, do the names (`f.fieldPath`) include the managed package namespace prefix?

Comment: What do you mean by saving the page? are you editing a packaged VF page in the installed org?..

Comment: What i meant was - submitting the VF page. ie when i click the  submit button to save the record

Comment: @KeithC - yes its giving out the namespace as well with f.fieldpath

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem. Works in dev-org but not when package is installed...

Comment: No. For us the issue was when we are using a site template which is not part of the managed package, we were getting this error. We overcame that providing the customization options within the template we were packaging