# "Variable not visible" error in production, but fine in development

Tags: apex, managed-package, controller

My managed package works fine in development. When it runs from client orgs, as an installed managed package, this error occurs:

"VisualForce Error

> Variable is not visible: [PackagePrefix.ControllerName].VariableName".

**Question**

Any ideas about the possible cause?

**Background info**

1. The controller passes all the test cases and has 100% code coverage with automated unit tests.
2. The relevant variable is declared like this:

   ```
   public Map<Integer,Attachment> VariableName {get; set;}
   ```
3. The class constructor method sets up the variable like this:

   ```
   VariableName = new Map<Integer, Attachment>();
   ```
4. The variable is only used from within the controller that creates
   it, and some VisualForce pages. The controller and the VisualForce
   pages are all part of the same managed package.
5. The error presents itself as an "Authorization Required" error to a
   typical user. By previewing the VisualForce page as an
   administrator, with Development Mode on, the real error message can
   be seen.
6. The virtual VisualForce user has very generous access privileges, so
   there isn't a permission problem here.
7. The code works fine when run locally in a client org (after adding
   the namespace to the objects, variables, etc). That, and the good
   test results, make me confident there isn't a simple coding problem.
8. The only job of the variable is to allow a VisualForce user to
   provide some file uploads that are to be saved as attachments to
   custom objects.

Comment: Well not sure about that, but please check your Pages and Classes versions, make sure that should be on same SF version.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked that. The class and all the VisualForce pages that use it are all on the same Api Version, 23.

Comment: Just want to be make sure, that's the salesforce API version which you checked?, not the managed package version. and compare the SF API version with version where it is working means in your Dev instance.

Comment: Yes, the API version for the class and for the VisualForce pages in the dev environment is 23.0, and it is also 23.0 in the client environment with the installed managed package. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Both the page and controller are within the managed package right?

Comment: Similar issue please check this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79887/variable-is-not-visible-controller-field-disp

Comment: The controller and the page are all in the same managed package.

Comment: Thanks @prasanthcheenu. That similar issue you mentioned says their solution was to  avoid using a 'a template outside the managed package'. I'm experiencing the problem even though the controller and VisualForce pages are all within the one managed package, and no templates are used at all.

Comment: I just upgraded the controller and all the related VisualForce pages to Salesforce.com API verison 39.0, re-released it as a managed package, installed the new version into a client environment, and tested it. There was no change to the result. The original error recurred.